# How to get subset if current price is greater than previous price?

Tags: r

I have a list of closing prices and dates.

```
      ï..Date  Close
1    3-Nov-17 172.50
2    2-Nov-17 168.11
3    1-Nov-17 166.89
4   31-Oct-17 169.04
5   30-Oct-17 166.72
6   27-Oct-17 163.05
7   26-Oct-17 157.41
8   25-Oct-17 156.41
9   24-Oct-17 157.10
10  23-Oct-17 156.17
11  20-Oct-17 156.25
12  19-Oct-17 155.98
13  18-Oct-17 159.76
14  17-Oct-17 160.47
15  16-Oct-17 159.88
16  13-Oct-17 156.99
17  12-Oct-17 156.00
18  11-Oct-17 156.55
19  10-Oct-17 155.90
20   9-Oct-17 155.84
```

I know how to apply a filter but what I really want to do is compare closing prices for each day and if the next price is higher than the current price I want to add it to a constantly growing subset.  Alternatively, if the current price is less than the previous price, I want to add this to a different subset.

The two subsets would essentially look like this.

```
3-Nov-17    172.5   B
2-Nov-17    168.11  B
31-Oct-17   169.04  B
30-Oct-17   166.72  B
27-Oct-17   163.05  B
26-Oct-17   157.41  B
24-Oct-17   157.1   B
20-Oct-17   156.25  B
17-Oct-17   160.47  B
16-Oct-17   159.88  B
13-Oct-17   156.99  B
11-Oct-17   156.55  B
10-Oct-17   155.9   B
9-Oct-17    155.84  B
```

Also.

```
1-Nov-17    166.89  S
25-Oct-17   156.41  S
23-Oct-17   156.17  S
19-Oct-17   155.98  S
18-Oct-17   159.76  S
12-Oct-17   156 S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text="
Date  Close
1    3-Nov-17 172.50
2    2-Nov-17 168.11
3    1-Nov-17 166.89
4   31-Oct-17 169.04
5   30-Oct-17 166.72
6   27-Oct-17 163.05
7   26-Oct-17 157.41
8   25-Oct-17 156.41
9   24-Oct-17 157.10
10  23-Oct-17 156.17
11  20-Oct-17 156.25
12  19-Oct-17 155.98
13  18-Oct-17 159.76
14  17-Oct-17 160.47
15  16-Oct-17 159.88
16  13-Oct-17 156.99
17  12-Oct-17 156.00
18  11-Oct-17 156.55
19  10-Oct-17 155.90
20   9-Oct-17 155.84
")

dt %>% mutate(group = ifelse(Close < lead(Close), "S", "B"))

#         Date  Close group
# 1   3-Nov-17 172.50     B
# 2   2-Nov-17 168.11     B
# 3   1-Nov-17 166.89     S
# 4  31-Oct-17 169.04     B
# 5  30-Oct-17 166.72     B
# 6  27-Oct-17 163.05     B
# 7  26-Oct-17 157.41     B
# 8  25-Oct-17 156.41     S
# 9  24-Oct-17 157.10     B
# 10 23-Oct-17 156.17     S
# 11 20-Oct-17 156.25     B
# 12 19-Oct-17 155.98     S
# 13 18-Oct-17 159.76     S
# 14 17-Oct-17 160.47     B
# 15 16-Oct-17 159.88     B
# 16 13-Oct-17 156.99     B
# 17 12-Oct-17 156.00     S
# 18 11-Oct-17 156.55     B
# 19 10-Oct-17 155.90     B
# 20  9-Oct-17 155.84  <NA>
```

You can split the updated dataset by column `group`. Not sure where the last row should belong, as you don't have the next value to compare with.

Comment: BRILLIANT!!  THANKS!!